# Wordpress - Links with diacritics won't load in Safari (Windows/MacOS/iPhone)

Tags: wordpress, safari

I have a website built on top of Wordpress and it has some links to some PDF files. Now, everything works fine in Chrome, IE, Firefox but not in Safari.

The problem is that I have some links including diacritics:

```
http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/hotărâre.pdf
```

This link works fine in all other browsers but in Safari *(Windows, Mac OS and iPhone)* I get the 404 page not found error.

Any idea on how can I fix this? Renaming the files will be a huge deal because there are over 15000 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename is in accented character. These characters are not recognized by iPhone, iPad, Mac too. If you want you to work on these devices, please do change the file name to the ASCII character.

For example, hotărâre.pdf can be hotarare.pdf which should open in Mac, iPhone and iPad.

Hope this will help you.

Thank You

Comment: I know I should do this but is there any way I can do it automatically? There are lots of files (over 15000) already attached in the website.

Comment: You can use Media File Renamer plugin to rename your pdf and media files. I have tested in my server and it is working absolutely fine. This may help you. 
Thank You

Comment: Thanks. I will select your answer.